# TTPhotoViewController is missing lower buttons

Tags: three20

I'm using Three20's TTPhotoViewController class within my tab based application and the image controls on the bottom don't show up.

Anyone know why the lower buttons dont show up?

I also get this bogus warning but I have no idea where it's coming from. `-[<CALayer: 0x5cb79a0> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (320.000000, 1110441984.000000)`

This is how I put the TTPhotoViewController into my view stack.

```
PhotosViewController *vc = [[[PhotosViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

[image: image of bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a little bug with the photoviewcontroller. (https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/604)

Try to redownload three20 v1.0.6.2, it should be fixed in that release